# ListView.getLastVisiblePosition() just after adapter is set

Tags: android, android-listview

This is the complete onPostExecute of my AsyncTask.

```
protected void onPostExecute(MergeAdapter mAdapter) {
    lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    isLoading = false;
    if (isActiveFragment())
       sProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();

    System.out.println( lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() );
    System.out.println( lv.getLastVisiblePosition()  );
    populateMarkers(lv.getFirstVisiblePosition(), lv.getLastVisiblePosition());
}
```

lv is the listview. So what I do is simply set the Adapter and just some moments after I ask the first and the last visible position.

The println-s output: 0 and -1. It looks that the objects have not been measured yet. Is it possible to get the first and the last position just after the adapter is set?

I want to run the `populateMarkers()` method with parameters the ints of the first and the last visible object.

Comment: you rebooted your listview, that's why all params in listview was reset also. what purpose of method populateMarkers? save listview positions?

Comment: @xoxol_89 Iterate a hashtable from first to last visible object. The first object would be `0` but the last depends on the device's screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the moment you call `getListView().getLastVisiblePosition()` the listview is not rendered. You can add the call to the view's message queue like this:

```
list.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println( lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() );
    System.out.println( lv.getLastVisiblePosition()  );
    populateMarkers(lv.getFirstVisiblePosition(), lv.getLastVisiblePosition());
    }
});
```